# Segmentation Violation on Napi::Function::Call

Tags: c++, node.js, segmentation-fault

I'm quite new to C/C++ and even moreso the NodeJS addon APIs. I'm trying to create a library to use the SDL2 C++ library from within Node and it's working for the most part, except when events are raised. The receiving NodeJS application polls for events 60 times a second. In the C++, I want to invoke a callback function when a certain type of event is raised. So in Node, I'll call the `setEventHandler(Event.Type, data => ... )` function, which binds the callback function to the event type. I do this like so:

```
// ./src/main.h

namespace node_sdl2 {

    SDL::SDL_Event event;

    ...

    Napi::Function mouseDown;
    Napi::Function mouseUp;

    void setListener(const Napi::CallbackInfo &info);

    ...

}

// ./src/main.cpp

void node_sdl2::setListener(const Napi::CallbackInfo &info) {

    Napi::Env env = info.Env();

    // Check the provided event type (info[0]) is the mouseMove event

    node_sdl2::mouseMove = info[1].As<Napi::Function>()

}
```

And this seems to work. I've used a method like this in other places throughout the code and this works fine. But as you may infer from the title, when I go to call the event handler, I get a segmentation violation. I call the function like so

```
// ./src/main.cpp

void node_sdl2::pollEvent(const Napi::CallbackInfo &info) {

    SDL::SDL_PollEvent(&node_sdl2::event);

    // again check for event type and if its the mouseMove event, call the respective handler.

    node_sdl2::mouseMove.Call({ ... args });

}
```

And this last line is the troublesome one. I'm aware that Segmentation Violations hint at dangling pointers, but the only place that would really come from is the reference to the callback. To be honest, I'm not certain how to confirm the callback actually exists, but I do know that I'm setting the handler before it is used from within the Node program. Is there a way to address this as I've been hanging here for a few days and not enough experience to resolve this myself.

Thanks